# search field in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

if i search for nodes in geometry nodes, i don't get some nodes as i want, at least not as others do.

e.g. in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/LVX6Ot3jvn8?t=240) of Cartesian Caramel he gets:

[image]

if i put "eq" in the search field, i will get:

[image]

Hint: i am working on a Mac

Is there any settings i can change so that i also get the "right" search results?

Comment: I'm on Windows. I don't know if that matters. That result will appear if you do as he does in the video and drag to the right from the Vertex Index 1 Node and type equal. Otherwise, as I'm sure you know, you have to set a Math Node to do what you want.

Comment: you are right! missed that detail - you can write an answer if you want, i will accept. Although i am still wondering what my result have to do with "eq"....

Comment: @Chris I don't know what the results have to do with "eq" either... when you press `F3` to search for "eq", the first results are all for something beginning with "sequencer", at least that's something I can comprehend... although I think it is very uncomfortable to have dozens of results shown first that you cannot use in the editor you are currently in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Chris said, he missed this in the video.

I have very little experience with Geometry Nodes. In addition to this case, I have seen in other tutorials that clicking and dragging from a node socket will get some search options for nodes that appear to me to be preconfigured for that type of socket in that node and that aren't available in that form using the standard search.

Click and drag from node socket:

[image]

Enter search terms:

[image]